# get Active Elements of canvas not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

how can i get active Object or Active Group in below Example ?? i am using this . in this fiddle i am trying to create curved text whenever text-box value is changed . i need to get active object of canvas to apply size and all changes but active group or element not working . how can i do this ?

Fiddle ::
http://jsfiddle.net/NHs8t/8/

Below snippts of fiffle::

```
        var act = canvas.getActiveGroup();

        var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
     if(!obj)
     {
        console.log('object not Selected');
     }else
     {
        console.log('Object  selected');
     }
     if (!canvas.getActiveGroup()) 
     {
        console.log('if part executed--object not selected');

        curvedText[cur] = new CurvedText(canvas, {});
        curvedText[cur].center();
        curvedText[cur].setText($(this).val());
        cur++;


    } else {
        console.log('Else part executed-object selected');
        act.setText($(this).val());

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getActiveGroup` seems to be buggy. `getActiveObject` returns the active group though, so you can go with that. Problem is you won't have access to your `setText` method through the group, so you'll have to keep a reference to the `CurvedText` instance in the group:

```
function CurvedText( canvas, options ){

  ...

  this.group.curvedText = this;
}
```

and then

```
var act = canvas.getActiveObject();
act.curvedText.setText($(this).val());
```

like I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NHs8t/10/).

Comment: you cant use control if u created another curved text . i want to make controls applicable for all curved text

Comment: solved this by using refence which u created . God Bless you !!:)

Comment: Yup, that should work, but the whole piece of code is designed to handle a single instance of `CurvedText`, what we did is a _hack_. I'd go with subclassing as explaine here http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#subclassing and define a `CurvedText` subclass of `fabric.Group`. That way `getActiveObject` would return an instance of this custom class, making having multipe instances of it possible.

Comment: How is `getActiveGroup` buggy?

Comment: I tried debugging the latest version of fabricjs and found this: `getActiveGroup: function () { return this._activeGroup; },`. I then set a breakpoint inside `setActiveGroup(group) { this._activeGroup = group }` and found out that when it gets called (it does not get called on click) the `group` parameter is `null`. These functions are the only ones containing `_activeGroup`. I debugged using the fiddle in this post and this version of fabric: http://fabricjs.com/build/files/text,cufon,gestures,easing,parser,freedrawing,interaction,serialization,image_filters,gradient,pattern,shadow,node.js

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. Are you saying there are times when active group exists, but `_activeGroup` is `null`? If so, I'd love to see jsfiddle (with latest version — https://raw.github.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/all.js) so that we can fix it! In any case, thanks for investigating :)

Comment: Here's a simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HAb4N/1/ Same behavior, `getActiveGroup` is `null` and `setActiveGroup` only gets called from within `discardActiveGroup`.

Comment: If you add `fabric.Group` to canvas you have to use `canvas.getActiveObject`. `canvas.getActiveGroup`is only for temporarily created groups ("selection group").
You can see it in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HAb4N/2/. Select both objects with mouse or with shift+click.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I don't know why I thaught there would be a separate method for selected group in the first place. Can't find a doc reference for it though. "Returns currently active group" is pretty misleading.